# SSIS 2008 connectivity to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We are upgrading our DB from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014, but we do not have plans to upgrade SSIS packages. Is it possible to use old SSIS packages with this latest migrated DB?

We have plan to migrate SSIS later if we can use same SSIS packages(2008) with SQL Server 2014.

Thanks

Comment: well then you need to exclude ssis from new installation or keep this in old server as stand alone

Comment: I am more concerned here for the connectivity issue, do i need to update\change the way we are connecting to the current DB or it can work they way it is right now.

Comment: Yes, your connection string changes due to Provider. You can change each package or use a config file and pass in new connection string

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your connection managers to use the correct Provider version for SQL 2014 connections, and of course change the connections strings as needed.   But SSIS 2008 packages can connect to SQL Server 2014 with no problem.